# How do I make vertical height of cards vary in Materialize CSS?

Tags: css, django-templates, materialize

I am trying to make it like an admin panel thingy. and for that, I am going for a pannel look and since I want it to be a little irregular I want the size of cards to vary. This is what I want to fix:[image]

I don't want the space that I have crossed out with red and I want the thing on the right to extend beyond its row, and I don't know how to do that?

My code(I am using Django and Materialize and a custom styling sheet for colours):

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content Vgrey white-text">
          <span class="card-title">Networth</span>
          <h3 class="center-align cardVtext">{{net_worth}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col s3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content Vgrey white-text">
          <span class="card-title">Balance</span>
          <h3 class="center-align cardVtext">{{balance}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>     
    </div>
    <div class="col s2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content Vgrey white-text">
          <span class="card-title">% Increase</span>
          <h3 class="center-align cardVtext">{{percentage_increase}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>     
    </div>
    <div class="col s4">
      <div class="card right ">
        <div class="card-content Vgrey white-text">
          <table class="highlight centered responsive-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Stocks Owned</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              {% for stock in portfolio %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{stock.stock_ticker}}</td>
                  <td>{{stock.stocks_owned}}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div> <!--First row ends here-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content Vgrey white-text">
          <span class="card-title">Networth</span>
          <canvas id="myChart"> </canvas>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div> <!--second row ends here-->






</div><!--Container ends here-->
```

Comment: CSS Grid can help in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered very well by a user on Reddit by the name of jonassalen.

> You just need another column layout in this example.
>
> First a row with 2 columns: In that first column you put the block
> with the 3 columns and the bigger block beneath. In the second column,
> you put the block on the right.